# How to query a related entity where the relationship is defined by a common set of secondary relations

Tags: sql

### Tables

```
KeyValue:
- id
- key
- value

TestEnvironment:
- id

TestEnvironmentProperties:
- test_env_id
- keyvalue_id

TestCommentary:
- id
- comment

TestCommentaryProperties:
- test_commentary_id
- keyvalue_id
```

### Example data

**KeyValue**

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | version | 1.2.3 |
| 2 | version | 7.8.9 |
| 3 | arch | x86 |
| 4 | arch | amd64 |

**TestEnvironment**

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

**TestEnvironmentProperties** (association table)

| test_env_id | keyvalue_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

**TestCommentary**

| id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Known issue: We don't work on 64-bit" |
| 2 | "This version never worked, woops!" |

**TestCommentaryProperties** (association table)

| test_commentary_id | keyvalue_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |

### Explanation

`TestEnvironment` is many-to-many with `KeyValue`, and `TestCommentary` is also many-to-many with `KeyValue`.

A test environment is defined purely by the arbitrary key-values that are related to it. With the example data above, there are 3 test environments defined:

| id | properties |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | version: 1.2.3; arch: x86 |
| 2 | version: 1.2.3; arch: amd64 |
| 3 | version: 7.8.9; arch: amd64 |

Test commentary is then defined in a similar manner, however the commentary about a test has its own set of key-values, as the commentary doesn't necessarily relate 1:1 with an exact test environment. Again with the example data above, the test commentary defined is:

| id | commentary | properties |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Known issue: We don't work on 64-bit" | arch: amd64 |
| 2 | "This version never worked, woops!" | version: 1.2.3 |

Conceptually, a `TestCommentary` is related to a `TestEnvironment` if the key-values attached to the `TestCommentary` is a sub-set of the key-values attached to the `TestEnvironment`.

For example if querying the comments related to each of the test environments, I'd get the following results:

`TestEnvironment.id = 1`

| environment_id | commentary_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "This version never worked, woops!" |

`TestEnvironment.id = 2`

| environment_id | commentary_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | "Known issue: We don't work on 64-bit" |
| 2 | 2 | "This version never worked, woops!" |

`TestEnvironment.id = 3`

| environment_id | commentary_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | "Known issue: We don't work on 64-bit" |

### Question

How do I construct a single query to selects the `TestCommentary` relating to a `TestEnvironment` without needing to dynamically create a query? I would like to be able to select with knowing only the `TestEnvironment` `id`.

Comment: Please update your question to provide sample data for the tables involved and the result you want to achieve based on that sample data

Comment: Thanks for having a look, I've updated the question with example tables and output.